# How to left justify a bottom annotation from ggarrange in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am trying to left justify some annotations below a plot created with `ggarrange`. For the life of me, I can't figure this out, nor can I find any documentation of what additional parameters in the `text_grob` command do.

Here is my code, and the figure is the result. It's centered which is not what I want.

```
voter_centric_plot <- ggarrange(plotenjoy, plotcitknow, ploteduresp, plotconduct, 
                                plotturnout, plotinclusion, plottimeedu)
voter_centric_plot_final <- annotate_figure(voter_centric_plot, 
                                            top = text_grob("Components of a Voter Centered Ethos of Election Administration", 
                                                            face = "bold", size = 14),
                                            bottom = text_grob("Data Source: 2020 LEO Survey. \n Horizontal lines  are average response; points are mean response by category with 95% confidence intervals. \n Items are sorted by overall level of agreement.",
                                                               size = 8))
```

The only example provided in the document (https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/annotate_figure.html) only provides an example of left justifying the annotation.

I know this isn't a replicable example but hoping someone may know the answer to what seems to me should be a relatively common question.

[Plot from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n1k7.png)

Answer (score 0):

The annotation as any `textGrob` will by default be positioned at the center, i.e. `x = y = unit(.5, "npc")`. Hence, to left justify your annotation you have to position it on the left using `x = unit(0, "npc")` and of course set `hjust=0` to align the text on the left. Additionally, in the code below I added some "padding" on the left by using `x = unit(5.5, "pt")`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  geom_point()

voter_centric_plot <- ggarrange(p1, p1, p1, p1)
voter_centric_plot_final <- annotate_figure(voter_centric_plot,
  top = text_grob("Components of a Voter Centered Ethos of Election Administration",
    face = "bold", size = 14
  ),
  bottom = text_grob(
    paste(
      "Data Source: 2020 LEO Survey.",
      "Horizontal lines  are average response; points are mean response by category with 95% confidence intervals.",
      "Items are sorted by overall level of agreement.",
      sep = "\n"
    ),
    size = 8,
    hjust = 0,
    x = unit(5.5, "pt")
  )
)
voter_centric_plot_final
```

[image]